# Testing stateful Mojolicious apps

Tags: perl, testing, automated-tests, mojolicious

I want to test hiding and unhiding of an entry. I conduct the following tests in Mojolicious t/basic.t:

```
my $t = Test::Mojo->new('AdminApi');
$t->get_ok('/publications/hide/1');
$t->get_ok('/read/publications/meta')->content_unlike(qr/Paper with id 1:/i);
$t->get_ok('/read/publications/meta/1')->content_like(qr/Cannot find entry id: 1/i);

$t->get_ok('/publications/unhide/1');
$t->get_ok('/read/publications/meta')->content_like(qr/Paper with id 1: <a href/i);
$t->get_ok('/read/publications/meta/1')->content_unlike(qr/Cannot find entry id: 1/i);
```

My problem is that the two lines '/publications/hide/1' and '/publications/unhide/1' do not hide and unhide the entry. The state of the entry remains untouched.

If I repeat the steps manually in the browser everything works well. For the obvious reasons I want to have it automated with the tests. How to do this?

EDIT: The calls '/publications/hide/1' and '/publications/unhide/1' change the state of the database - just a simple UPDATE query. The change applies to the whole application - for all users. But one needs to be logged in as a user to hide/unhide. Question: how do I emulate a logged user during the test?

Contents generated by '/read/publications/meta' and '/read/publications/meta/1' can be read without login.

[Bitbucket Repo](https://bitbucket.org/vikin9/hex64publicationlistmanager)

[File with test code: basic.t](https://bitbucket.org/vikin9/hex64publicationlistmanager/src/70d1925d5f9e3db9da689c223081e438703b8ed6/t/basic.t?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: Are the `/publications/hide/1` and `/publications/unhide/1` changes in the state of the ressource inside of the application on the server? Is that state related to the _user_, or in general to the _overal application_? Does `$t` have a session cookie and does it keep the same session for each request it makes with `get_ok`?

Comment: I added the missing info and links to the code repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already said, you need to be logged in to perform the `hide` and `unhide` action.

> ```
> my $t = Test::Mojo->new('AdminApi');
> ```

You are creating a new UserAgent here. The Test::Mojo class inherits from Mojo::UserAgent. It has a `cookie_jar` and thus keeps a session alive. You need that to perform this action:

> ```
> $t->get_ok('/publications/hide/1');
> ```

But right now you are not logged in. What you need to do is log in the user. Looking at the [code in your repository](https://bitbucket.org/vikin9/hex64publicationlistmanager/src/70d1925d5f9e3db9da689c223081e438703b8ed6/t/basic.t?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#basic.t-7), you actually assert that you are **not logged in**.

> ```
>  $t->get_ok('/')->status_is(200)->content_like(qr/Please login or register/i);
> ```

Before you perform the `hide`, you need to log in the user. After digging a bit in your code I found the action and [the template](https://bitbucket.org/vikin9/hex64publicationlistmanager/src/70d1925d5f9e3db9da689c223081e438703b8ed6/templates/login/index.html.ep?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) to do that, so I know what the request needs to look like.

```
$t->post_ok(
    '/do_login' => { Accept => '*/*' },
    form        => { user   => 'admin', pass => 'hunter2' }
);
```

Now your `$t` UserAgent *should be logged in* and you can do the `hide`. Note that [`get_ok`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Mojo#get_ok) only checks if there was no *transport error*. So in fact it would make sense to now check if in fact you are now logged in.

You could do that by introspecting the session in the application, by checking the logfile (you are writing `"Login success"` there) or by checking the page for some string that says that the user is logged in. In [templates/display/start.html.ep](https://bitbucket.org/vikin9/hex64publicationlistmanager/src/70d1925d5f9e3db9da689c223081e438703b8ed6/templates/display/start.html.ep?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#start.html.ep-9) there is a text that welcomes the logged-in user, so you can use that.

```
$t->post_ok(
    '/do_login' => { Accept => '*/*' },
    form        => { user   => 'admin', pass => 'hunter2' }
)->text_like(qr/Nice to see you here admin/i);
```

Because `text_like` uses the text-nodes, the `<em>` around the username is not relevant in the test.

Right, now we know you are logged in. Time to switch the thing on and off.

```
$t->get_ok('/publications/hide/1');
```

Because there is no obvious error thrown for that as far as I can tell, I don't see how to test the success of that. Status code is one way, but there might be something in the content as well that you could test.

To verify the state of the application, you would now call the publication.

> ```
> $t->get_ok('/read/publications/meta')->content_unlike(qr/Paper with id 1:/i);
> $t->get_ok('/read/publications/meta/1')->content_like(qr/Cannot find entry id: 1/i);
> ```

Right. But remember, our `$t` is still logged in. Maybe the logged-in user is allowed to see hidden stuff as well as unhidden stuff. Maybe they are not.

It's probably safer to make a second UserAgent that's not logged in, and check with that one as well.

```
# check with an unauthorized user
my $t_not_logged_in = Test::Mojo->new('AdminApi');
$t_not_logged_in
  ->get_ok('/read/publications/meta')
  ->content_unlike(qr/Paper with id 1:/i);
$t_not_logged_in
  ->get_ok('/read/publications/meta/1')
  ->content_like(qr/Cannot find entry id: 1/i);
```

Now basically you repeat the same thing by unhiding your content and testing again. Rinse and repeat.

---

Keep in mind that unless you are using an explicit testing database (which you seem not to do), you cannot be sure that there even is an entry 1. Or what the name of that is. You should use fixtures for the tests. You could, for example, create a fresh instance of the DB using sqlite and work with that.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot! Now, I can finish writing the tests properly. I have a separate server for testing where I can quickly reset the database to a predefined state. I am doing it using a bash script, but I may add some perl code for that to automate even more.

Comment: For the future: the fragment "Because `text_like` uses the text-nodes, the <em> around the username is not relevant in the test." seems not to be true in the current version. You need to use there `content_like`.

Comment: I have no recollection of writing this answer, but I believe you are correct @Piotr :)